# how to make multiple splats in react router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to upgrade to react router 6, and I'm breaking when trying to use more than one splat per path.

basically, I'm trying to do

```
/* ~~> project page
/*/~code/* ~~> file page
```

here are some examples of the project page:

- https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/nav-link
- https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/graph/tree/root-node
- https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/compare-url
- https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/hooks/use-graphql-light

here are some examples of a file page (and other subpages)

- [https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/nav-link/~code](https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/nav-link/%7Ecode)
  [https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/layout/grid-component/~code/grid-template/grid-template.module.scss](https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/layout/grid-component/%7Ecode/grid-template/grid-template.module.scss)
- [https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/compare-url/~code/compare-url.tsx](https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/routing/compare-url/%7Ecode/compare-url.tsx)
- [https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/input/button/~dependencies](https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/input/button/%7Edependencies)
- [https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/input/button/~compositions](https://hu9y25l.scopes.teambit.cloud/input/button/%7Ecompositions)

This is not unique to our company. You can see it in other sites, like github: (although you could argue they have a fixed length for the owner)
https://github.com/teambit/bit/tree/master/src/doctor.

since React Router v4, I used to solve it with path-to-regexp, like this:

```
<Route path="/:project(\\w)"><ProjectPage/></Route>
<Route path="/:project(\\w)/~code/:file(.*)"><FilePage/></Route>
```

but in v6, this doesn't seem to be the case anymore (see [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-route-path-patterns))

> React Router v6 uses a simplified path format.  in v6 supports only 2 kinds of placeholders: dynamic :id-style params and * wildcards. A * wildcard may be used only at the end of a path, not in the middle.

I honestly expected this syntax to work, but it is not allowed

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="*" element={<ProjectPage/>} />
  <Route path="*/~code" />
    <Route index element={<FilePage/>} />
    <Route path="*" element={<FilePage/>} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This takes us back to react router 2, where we had to do this type of routing manually.

It's crazy, React Router had only one job. Is there a way to achieve this type of dynamic urls in React Router 6?

Comment: What is unclear about "A * wildcard may be used only at the end of a path, not in the middle."? The `"*"` is only used to indicate a route can match additional nested routes it may be rendering. What is the use case you are trying to solve for?

Comment: I'm trying to make _nested_ routes which are _dynamic_, ie
`/*/~code/*`. The first * should match the owner project (including `/`) but stop before the `~code`, and the second * should match everything else

Comment: `react-router-dom@6` doesn't work that way. You'll have to be explicit then with any parent routes you want to match/render.

Comment: but that's what a routing system is for ‍♂️. this really hurts!

Comment: I realized it simplified ranking, so RR6 now knows better which route to render without relying on order, but it's a huge feature that got removed!

Comment: Is there an issue with rendering a `<Route path="/teambit/base-ui/routing/routing-provider/*" .... />` parent layout route around the routes you are trying to use above? The `ProjectPage` is rendered on an index route, and then next route is `<Route path="~code"> ... </Route>`.

Comment: the parent route is also dynamic. so (a) I can't specify `/teambit/base-ui/routing/routing-provider/*` hard coded'ly, and (b) it will also swallow the file page. I can't even place `<Route path="/~code">` anywhere in the code!

Comment: Please edit your question to include *all* the relevant code you are trying to use and work with, and clarify the use case, i.e. what *exactly* you are trying to do, including examples. What is dynamic about the path segments leading up to the code snippet you shared? Like I said, in RRDv6 you need to be explicit about what you are matching.

Comment: I added some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another approach would be to dynamically generate routes according to custom matches, like so:

```
const parentRegex = /([^~]*[^~/])(\/~)?/;
function NestedRoute() {
    const params = useParams();
    const splat = params["*"];

    const match = splat ? parentRegex.exec(splat) : null;
    const parentPath = match ? match[1] : "/";

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path={`${parentPath}/*`}>
                <Route index element={<ProjectPage id={parentPath} />} />
                <Route
                    path="~code/*"
                    element={<CodePage projectId={parentPath} />}
                />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

it works, though it got some drawbacks:

- It couples the `ProjectPage` to the `CodePage` (where as before they just needed to know the same "path"
- It's not generic
- It will probably break in the next release of React Router

Comment: I think this is the answer. I'll mark it as the solution if there's no better choice

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, it's not possible. for example:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="*" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path="*/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} /> {/* <--- this is just ignored */}
                <Route path="hello/~code" element={<div>specific code page</div>} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

- generic code page is never reachable.
- hello/~code ~> will show "specific code page"
- anything else will get "catch all page"

it seems that params allowing `"/"` are no longer possible

I could do this, but it's not why I have a routing system:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path=":id" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3/:id4" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3/:id4/:id5" element={<div>catch all page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3/:id4/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} />
                <Route path=":id/:id2/:id3/:id4/:id5/~code" element={<div>generic code page</div>} />
                <Route path="hello/~code" element={<div>specific code page</div>} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should nest the routes:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path=":project" element={<ProjectPage/>} />
</Routes>
```

I'd make `<ProjectPage/>` a recursive element with nested inner `<Routes/>` in order to catch every `/:project/`, and stop when I happen upon `/~code/`; it indeed seems convoluted in comparison to v5.

Comment: ah and collect the params in every recursion? until I hit `<Route index element={<ActualPage id={accumulatedPath} />}/>` or `<Route path="/~code/*" element={<CodePage/>}/>`

Comment: Seems so. Or you can utilize the useparams hook in react router.

Comment: Sorry- seems that useLocation would be more useful. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location

Comment: yes but not if the route is nested, ie `/projects/:project(.*)/~file/:file(.*)` and so on

Comment: From the docs it seems like this should work in a nested path. I’ll try to write a demo soon.